# raw_input while loop not working

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

Just for fun I wanted to create a python MADLIB. Code is below:

```
print "WELCOME TO MADLIBS! PY V1.2.1"
print ""
print "To see the story type all thirteen parts of speech below"
print ""
print "1. Foreign Country"
print "2. Adverb"
print "3. Adjective"
print "4. Animal"
print "5. Verb (ing)"
print "6. Verb"
print "7. Verb (ing)"
print "8. Adverb"
print "9. Adjective"
print "10. A Place"
print "11. Type of Liquid"
print "12. Part of the Body"
print "13. Verb"
print ""

while 13:
num=raw_input("Enter: ")
```

I want to loop the variable `num` 13 times and somehow grab the first through thirteenth inputs and print them like so:

```
print "If you are traveling in" num "and find yourself having to cross a piranha-filled river, here's how to do it" num ". Piranhas are more" num "during the day, so cross the river at night. Avoid areas with netted" num "traps - piranhas may be" num "there looking to" num "them! When" num "the river, swim" num ". You don't want to wake them up and make them" num "! Whatever you do, if you have an open wound, try to find another way to get back to the" num ". Piranhas are attracted to fresh" num "and will most likely take a bite out of your" num "if you" num "in the water!"
```

If you have a better solution or a fixed version of mine I would love to hear it.

Comment: 1. You want a `for` loop. 2. You reassign `num` each time, so can only ever access the last input; you should use a `list` instead. 3. That is not how you handle strings, at the very least you need commas and you should really use string formatting. Please see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html

Comment: A solution would probably help you less than reading more about Python. Depending on how much you already know about programming, you have resources likes Instant Python, Snake Wrangling for Kids, the official tutorial…

Comment: I know it's just a little hard to grasp, and what better of a way to learn than to actually code. Sometimes you have to get your hands dirty coding, being confused, and then feeling like a baus when you accomplish something!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version:

```
input_types = ['Foreign Country', 'Adverb', 'Adjective', 'Animal', 'Verb (ing)']
input_types.append('Verb')
input_types.append('Verb (ing)')
input_types.append('Adverb')
input_types.append('Adjective')
input_types.append('A Place')
input_types.append('Type of Liquid')
input_types.append('Part of the Body')
input_types.append('Verb')

story = '''If you are traveling in {} and find yourself having to cross
a piranha-filled river, here's how to do it {}.
Piranhas are more {} during the day, so cross the river at night.
Avoid areas with netted {} traps - piranhas may be {} there looking to {} them!
When {} the river, swim {}. You don't want to wake them up and make them {}!
Whatever you do, if you have an open wound,
try to find another way to get back to the {}.
Piranhas are attracted to fresh {} and will most likely take a bite out
of your {} if you {} in the water!'''

print('WELCOME TO MADLIBS! PY V1.2.1\n')
print('To see the story type all thirteen parts of speech below')

results = []

for number, value in enumerate(input_types):
    user_input = raw_input('#{} - {}: '.format(number+1, value))
    results.append(user_input)

print('Here is your story: ')
print(story.format(*results))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Pure awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should use, **arrays** and **string formatting**. This will make your code clearer and easier to handle, apart from the fact that it would make it more pythonic. A solution for your script would be something like this:

```
print "WELCOME TO MADLIBS! PY V1.2.1"
print ""
print "To see the story type all thirteen parts of speech below"
print ""
print "1. Foreign Country"
print "2. Adverb"
print "3. Adjective"
print "4. Animal"
print "5. Verb (ing)"
print "6. Verb"
print "7. Verb (ing)"
print "8. Adverb"
print "9. Adjective"
print "10. A Place"
print "11. Type of Liquid"
print "12. Part of the Body"
print "13. Verb"
print ""

num = 0
answers = []

while num < 13:
    val = raw_input("Enter %s: " num + 1)
    answers.append(val)
    num += 1

answer = """If you are traveling in %s and find yourself having to cross
a piranha-filled river, here's how to do it %s.
Piranhas are more %s during the day, so cross the river at night.
Avoid areas with netted %s traps - piranhas may be %s there looking to %s them!
When %s the river, swim %s. You don't want to wake them up and make them %s!
Whatever you do, if you have an open wound,
try to find another way to get back to the %s.
Piranhas are attracted to fresh %s and will most likely take a bite out
of your %s if you %s in the water!""" % (answers[0], answers[1], answers[2],
    answers[3], answers[4], answers[5], answers[6], answers[7], answers[8],
    answers[9], answers[10], answers[11], answers[12])

print answer
```

You save the values in an array, which allows you to have more than one value inside it and then format it in a long string which allows you to see your output better.

Comment: If you use `str.format` instead of `%`, you can just use `"...".format(*answers)`.

Comment: Well the array makes sense, but for some reason it's saying there is something wrong with **num** under the while num < 13:

Comment: @jonrsharpe I didn't know you could format a whole list like that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @el_coder That's because arrays start at **0 not 1**. SO your array goes from 0 to 12 and still has 13 elements.

Comment: @LeandroPoblet I know that, I'm not stupid. It makes sense. But it still says **num** is invalid syntax!?!?!